# Oracle Toad SQL queries leading to inconsistent id counts

Tags: sql, oracle, compare, subquery, toad

I'm using Oracle Toad with SQL commands in the editor window.

I created two new tables (`PIDS1` and `PIDS2`) that contain only one column of ID numbers from two related tables.

I had expected that `PIDS2` would contain a superset of the ID's in `PIDS1`. When I tried to identify the ID's in `PIDS2` that are not in `PIDS1`, I got started on a wild goose chase.

Let's say that it is a given that there is something unexpected going on with the data in my tables. But I cannot make any sense of the two simplified queries described below. The numbers are inconsistent. Can someone explain what is going on?

```
-- PIDS1 IS A SINGLE-COLUMN TABLE THAT CONTAINS 1638061 DISTINCT ID'S
-- PIDS2 IS A SINGLE-COLUMN TABLE THAT CONTAINS 3510272 DISTINCT ID'S

SELECT COUNT(T2.ID)
    FROM PIDS2 T2
    WHERE T2.ID NOT IN (
        SELECT T1.ID
        FROM PIDS1 T1);

-- RESULT IS ZERO!
-- WTF? PIDS2 HAS MORE ID'S THAN PIDS1!

SELECT COUNT(T1.ID)
    FROM PIDS1 T1
    WHERE T1.ID NOT IN (
        SELECT T2.ID
        FROM PIDS2 T2);

-- RESULT IS 786690
-- WHERE DID THAT NUMBER COME FROM? LOOKS ARBITRARY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use `NOT IN` with a subquery.  If *any* of the values returned by the subquery are `NULL`, then *all* rows are filtered out.

For this reason, I always advise `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT T2.ID
FROM PIDS2 T2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PIDS1 T1 WHERE t1.ID = T2.ID);
```

Of course, you can also add `WHERE t1.ID IS NOT NULL` to the `NOT IN` version.  In my experience, you'll forget it at some inopportune time in the future.  Just use `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: When I try "not exists" I get "ora-00920: invalid relational operator"

But the following code does what I want:
`-- STEP 3 REVISITED

SELECT COUNT(T2.ID)
 FROM PIDS2 T2
 WHERE T2.ID IS NOT NULL AND T2.ID NOT IN (
  SELECT T1.ID
  FROM PIDS1 T1
  WHERE T1.ID IS NOT NULL);`

Comment: Note that I had to put "IS NOT NULL" for the T2.ID _and_  the T1.ID

Comment: Using NOT EXISTS would be a better solution, but my oracle sql doesn't like it. Is there a different syntax that would work in oracle?

Comment: Oracle supports NOT EXISTS for decades, there must be something else causing that error.